# Access to next array item in handlebars.js

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

I need access to next item in array while using foreach loop in handlebars.js.I've tried:

```
{{#each items}}
{{#ifEven @index}}
<p>{{this.description}} - {{../items.[@index+1].description}}</p>
{{/ifEven}}
{{/each}}
```

but it seems that's not working correctly.

Comment: This is going to break as soon as you reach the last item in the array. Why do you need to include the next item in the current one?

Comment: Because I'm displaying only even items. If next item is odd, I want to put it's description in current iteration.

Comment: In that case you are doing too much on your template. It is best if you prepare your array before rendering. Templates should have as few logic as possible to avoid weird, hard to debug and trace errors.

Comment: Sure, but I wanted to keep it in template file for some reasons. I just solved this issue by using helper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already solved it using helper:

```
hbs.registerHelper('nextItem', function (array, index, options) {
  return options.fn(array[index + 1]);
});
```

And .hbs template now looks like this:

```
{{#each items}}
{{#ifEven @index}}
<p>{{this.description}} - {{#nextItem ../items index}} {{description}} {{/nextItem}}</p>
{{/ifEven}}
{{/each}}
```

I know, that last element will not show, but this doesn't matter in my case.